# go to path and then tar?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, tar

Can you have tar travel to a certain direct and then tar files relative to that directory? All while using one command (tar)?

For example instead of doing

```
cd /home/test/backups; tar zvPcf backup.tar.gz ../data/
```

I could do something like

```
tar -g '/home/test/backups/' zvPcf backup.tar.gz ../data/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
tar zvPcf /home/test/backups/backup.tar.gz /home/test/backups/../data/
```

Answer (score 9):

see the -C option.

the tar man page gives this example :

```
   tar -xjf foo.tar.bz2 -C bar/
          extract bzipped foo.tar.bz2 after changing directory to bar
```

might be what you're looking for ...

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

> `tar zvPcf backup.tar.gz ../data/ -C '/home/test/backups/'`

Answer (score 1):

See [tar(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar).

> `-C, --directory DIR`  
>   change to directory DIR